# Is there "easy" way to use protobuf for JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, protocol-buffers

I'm making TCG game with JavaFX. I create protobuf file to represent various game status. Here is some snippet of protobuf I wrote:

```
message Board {
    repeated GameObject mainDeck = 1;
    repeated GameObject hand = 2;
    repeated GameObject graveyard = 3;
    repeated GameObject exile = 4;
    repeated Character character = 5;
}

message Character {
    optional GameObject character = 1;
    repeated GameObject item = 2;
    optional Position position = 3 [default = STAND];
}
```

JavaFX are using "Observable" things heavily. For example, I wrote this code to "bind" character image with its status:

```java
private final ObjectProperty<Character> character = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "character", Character.getDefaultInstance());

private void initialize() {
    // Other initialize code omitted
    ImageView img = new ImageView();
    StringBinding url = Bindings.select(character, "character", "imageUrl");
    img.imgProperty.bind(() -> ImageCache.getImage(url.get()), url);
    ObjectBinding<Position> p = Bindings.select(character, "position");
    img.rotateProperty.bind(
        Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            if (p.get() == null) {
                return 0.0;
            }
            switch (p.get()) {
                case REST:
                    return 90.0;
                case REVERSE:
                    return 180.0;
                default:
                    return 0.0;
            }
        }, p));
}
```

Note that I'm using immutable protobuf object here.

However, as you know, game status of TCG is highly dynamic, and changes could be happen either whole chunk (a character is dead; the character and all items it had are going to graveyard), or small piece (some powerful magic disintegreates a item; the item is going to exile zone).

With immutable protobuf object, it would be hard and/or inefficient to support such dynamics.

However, to use mutable protobuf object (=builder), it is necessary to wrap every field as Observable, and should not use original builder. It is not impossible but seems too tedious work.

Is there some library (or code generator?) to use protobuf easily with JavaFX?